# grep subset index referencing

Tags: r

Say I have a list in R

```
alist<-c("a","a","b","c")
```

now I want to take a subset of that list `alist[c(2,3,4)]`

if I apply the `grep` function to the subset i.e.

```
grep("b",alist[c(2,3,4)])
```

I will get 2. Is there anyway to use the `grep` function so that I get the position of `b` in the original list and not the subset? So instead of 2 the `grep` function will return 3?

Comment: Why can't you use `grep` on the original list to get the original position?

Comment: ok - I'll ask the obvious. Why do you need to take the subset if you don't want the position returned to be of that subset of the data?

Comment: @Joshua Ulrich & @Chase: his small example doesn't show it, but there is a chance that there could be an element in the original list that would match the regex but is not in the sublist.  Hence the need for an `intersection()` call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could simply run `grep()` on the original list

```
matches <- grep("b",alist)
```

Then do an intersection with your index vector

```
intersect(matches, c(2,3,4))
```

That way, you get the index in the original list, but only those items that are also included in the sublist.

Of course, you could do it all together in one line

```
intersect(grep("b",alist), c(2,3,4))
```

And it starts to look a lot like your original `grep()` statement in the question.

Comment: wow thanks thats really amazing. Its really efficient for what I'm doing too!